# How to expose SOAP endpoint for a RIA service?

Tags: wcf-ria-services

I have a WCF RIA service, a silverlight application and I should also support other kinds of application like WPF and others. By default, the SL app uses binary over http for communication with the service. Is it possible to expose a SOAP endpoint for the RIA service so that non SL applications can consume the service via SOAP endpoint ?

Comment: Looks like Silverlight developers don't branch out much... I like to use the Entity Framework alongside Domain Services, but mostly because I want to build a Business Objects repository that I can consume from multiple interfaces, be they Silverlight, Mobile, etc. I still haven't found a way to manually add an endpoint to web.config for a DomainService, though if I do, I'll come back with an answer.

Comment: i have added answer to my question.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to expose RIA service via SOAP.

By adding below line to the configuration file it is possible to expose SOAP end point for RIA services

```
<add name="Soap" type="Microsoft.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.SoapXmlEndpointFactory,             Microsoft.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
                       PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
```

Reference. 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davrous/archive/2010/12/03/how-to-open-a-wcf-ria-services-application-to-other-type-of-clients-the-soap-endpoint-3-5.aspx

Disclaimer - I haven't implemented it.